# gulp always changes the shell window's title to "gulp"

Tags: gulp

gulp always changes the cmd.exe windows' title to "gulp"
That’s quite inconvenient since I run a few gulp windows simultaneously and I’d like to differ them. It should work like this:

```
title 'My project Name'
gulp
```

But it doesn't.